# static метод не работает метод в Java

Tags: java, массивы, static

Прочитал пока только 30% книги Head First Java. Не могу понять один момент. В статическом методе `main` вызываю тоже статический метод `sortArray`, который получает на вход массив и сортирует его от меньшего к большему.

Так вот несмотря на то, что задаю в аргументе массив, метод в упор не хочет работать. Ему не нравятся типы, и я не могу понять, что не так.

Даем массив, принимаем на вход массив, возвращаем массив... Что же не так ???

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        sortArray(23, 33, 5);
    }
    
    static int[] sortArray (int[] myArr) {
        int tmp;
        for (int i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
            for (int x = i + 1; x < myArr.length; x++) {
                if (myArr[x] < myArr[i]) {
                    tmp = myArr[i];
                    myArr[i] = myArr[x];
                    myArr[x] = tmp;
                }
            }
        }
    
        for (int i : myArr) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
        return myArr;
    }
}
```

Сообщение об ошибке

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что не так? Ты не знаешь что такое массивы)) потому что на вход ты даёшь не массив, а три значения инт

Comment: Капец я олень, понял ! На вход мы должны подать название массива. Спасибо !!!!

Comment: Ну либо переменную с типом int[], где будут эти числа, либо сразу на лету дать массив `{23, 33, 5}`

Comment: А можно пожалуйста в виде кода, как на лету дать массив ?

Comment: Я уже написал это выше

Comment: Если не получится, то `new int[] {23, 33, 5}`

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы отработал существующий код без изменений в методе `main`, можно определить метод `sortArray`, как принимающий последовательность целых чисел переменной длины (vararg) `int ... arr`, а не массив `int[] arr`:

```
static int[] sortArray(int ... myArr) {
// ...
}

public static void main(String ... args) {
    int[] sorted = sortArray(23, 33, 5);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sorted)); // -> 5 23 33 [5, 23, 33]
}
```

Следует отметить, что при таком определении метода `sortArray` корректно будут обработаны оба варианта вызовов:

```
sortArray(14, 8, 27);             // 8 14 27
System.out.println("\n---");      // ---
sortArray(new int[] {14, 8, 27}); // 8 14 27
```

---

Или же можно изменить вызов `sortArray` в методе `main`, чтобы *правильно* передать массив, а не последовательность произвольной длины:

```java
public static void main(String ... args) {
    sortArray(new int[] {23, 33, 5}); // -> 5 23 33 
}
```